# Battery usage for "mobile network standby" even without SIM-card

Tags: battery, mobile-network

I have a phone reserved for development, which has never seen a SIM-card (to avoid accidental use of expensive amounts of data transfer).

Now, when checking battery usage, I see 4% accounted to "mobile network standby".

So what's wrong here?

No SIM-card == no mobile network, right?

I've seen this [Android data usage shows significant usage even without SIM card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/53169/338310) but it talks about data usage, *not* mobile network."

Edit:

@Robert sugested:

*"If you want to disable cellular activate Air-plane mode and then reactivate Wifi+Bluetooth if needed (phone will still be in Air-plane mode)."*

And it looks as if this is working. I Still have 4% battery loss (over the time of 2-3 days), but the phone does no longer attribute it to "mobile network standby", so hopefully it is really only internal battery discharge.

Comment: [Enable developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options), disable *mobile data always active* and check

Comment: [Requests that your app makes to the network are a major cause of battery drain because they turn on the power-hungry mobile or Wi-Fi radios. Beyond the power needed to send and receive packets, these radios expend extra power just turning on and keeping awake. Something as simple as a network request every 15 seconds can keep the mobile radio on continuously and quickly use up battery power](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/network) //so your apps keep requesting access irrespective of SIM being present or not and therefore suggestion above should help

Comment: @beeshyams that sounds good, Settings->(Edit)->System->Developer options->[from many, many options, choose]: mobile data always active It will take a few days to verify.

Comment: My hunch is that it should solve but only verification can confirm. You can charge the phone fully and test overnight. That should give a fair estimate (without interruption of your development work)

Comment: No SIM card does not mean no mobile network. In some countries you can still make emergency calls without a SIM card. Therefore the phone constantly searches for local cellular networks. If you want to disable cellular activate Air-plane mode and then reactivate Wifi+Bluetooth if needed (phone will still be in Air-plane mode).

Comment: @beeshyams Your proposal does not work on my phone. It has a strong battery, so one day to verify is not enough. After the first try, "mobile network standby" was 11%, but checking the switches, "mobile data always active", somehow, was "On" again. I recharged and checked again, it is "Off" now but has still drawn another 4%.

Comment: @Robert as beeshyams's advice does not work (don't know why, sounded real good) I will try yours. Your hint on emergency calls is valuable, especially if someone needs an emergency call that is not working ... .

Comment: @GyroGearloose A lot of country already have disabled possibility to make an emergency call without SIM because it was massively abused by people making fun calls. I remember one case where some one (not a child) was making more than 100 emergency calls during one weekend.

Comment: @Robert that's a shame. But I really miss the possibility to make some test calls, not to the emergency people but to some automaton, just to make sure it would work if needed.